# On a base 10 Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, closed-form, transcendental-numbers

What is the sum of the reciprocals of numbers with only $0$'s and $1$'s in their base $10$ expansion? $$x=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{110}+\frac{1}{111}+\cdots.$$ Is the result transcendental, and does it have a closed form? I have figured out that $1.238405615301<x<1.238405615306$, but do not know where to go from there.

Comment: Before asking whether it's trancendental, maybe we should be certain that it's irrational. Also, is your interest in this specific constant just pure curiosity, or do you have a specific reason to be looking into it?

Comment: It looks like a really thinned out version of the Kempner-Irwin sum...

Comment: If we consider
$$ f(z)=\prod_{k\geq 0}(1+z^{10^k}) $$
then
$$ x = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(z)-1}{z}\,dz $$
where $f(z)$ fulfills the functional equation $f(z^{10})=(1+z)^{-1}\,f(z)$, allowing an accurate numerical evaluation of the previous integral.

Comment: Then we may also try to prove the irrationality of $x$ through a Beuker-like approach, i.e. by considering $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(z)-1}{z}z^a(1-z)^b\,dz.$$

Comment: If I use [Schmelzer's algorithm](https://github.com/tschm/Kempner), I get $1.23840561531$ as an estimate of the sum.

Comment: I'm looking at this problem, because, as Jack D'Aurizio said, this sum is linked to $$f(z)=\prod_{k \geq 0} (1+z^{10^k}) ,$$ which in turn is related to the number of partitions with $10^k$.

Comment: Thank you for calling it Schmelzer's algorithm :-)  The link is now broken. Please use https://github.com/tschm/sage. A more accurate estimate is 1.238405615305594809710656044712311849332635985681546736306864425647666592499558769852717907545517521

Comment: Are you still  in high school? And doing tensors ? Wow