# Irrationality of $1+1/10+1/11+1/100+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$'th smallest whole number with digits strictly $0$ or $1$ be expressed by $f(n)$. While all of these numbers look binary, we are working in entirely base 10.

> Is it possible to prove that $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n) =\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\text{...}\approx 1.238... $$
>   is irrational?

I have been working on trying to move this sum into a different form, and only partially succeeded. This was done by grouping the summed numbers in differing ways.

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty\text{ }\text{ }\sum_{n={\lfloor \log f(m)\rfloor+1}}^\infty\frac{1}{10^{n}+f(m)}$$

While my goal with this change was to compare with various Lambert Series, I found myself a little bit lost.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: multiply each by 10 and you'll be able to find 9 times the sum by subtracting out the original sum. As terms cancel.

Comment: Also asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2513695/420432 . There's some more information there, but no definitive answer.

Comment: @nickgard Appreciate you posting the other question. In my opinion, this is distinctly different because I am aiming for irrationality alone before seeing if the value is transcendental.